# Destructor of vector of object

Tags: c++

**Hello,**

I have in my class Ordinateur a vector of *Composant :

```
class Ordinateur {

string type;
vector<Composant*> Composants;

...

}
```

How do i write my destructor ? I read **a lot of contradictory answers** here on StackOverflow so i'm a bit lost.

**1st version :**

```
virtual ~Ordinateur()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Composants.size(); i++)
    {
        delete Composants[i];
    }
    Composants.clear();
}
```

**2nd Version**

```
virtual ~Ordinateur()
{
    Composants.clear();
}
```

**What about :**

```
 virtual ~Ordinateur()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Composants.size(); i++)
    {
        delete Composants[i];
    }

}
```

I would like to avoid memory leaks ...

Comment: Use smart pointers. Nothing will need to be written

Comment: I'm working on a project where we can't use smart pointers ...

Comment: Why not? Seems very limiting

Comment: The `clear()` is useless in both cases. Obviously `vector` will do that much itself!

Comment: Where are these contradictory answers? The correct way to write your destructor is completely uncontroversial, if there are answers suggesting anything else they need to be corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the first version **if you allocated the `Composant` elements using `new Composant();`** otherwise the second version will leak memory.

```
virtual ~Ordinateur()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Composants.size(); i++)
    {
        delete Composants[i]; // this is needed to free the memory
    }
    // Composants.clear(); // not needed vector cleans itself up
}
```

However you may consider doing this instead:

```
class Ordinateur {

    std::string type;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Composant>> Composants;

    ...

}
```

Then you don't need to write a *destructor* at all, the elements will *delete* themselves. And there is no need to call `Composants.clear();` in the *destructor* because the *vector* will do that itself when your object is destroyed.

Answer (score 4):

If the vector owns them and they point to `new`'ed objects, then your first variant is correct.

The call to vector::clear() is not necessary. It will be done by the destructor anyway. It does nothing bad apart from wasting CPU cycles though.

You should still use smart pointers, so you don't have such problems.

Comment: The call to `clear()` is unnecessary as that will happen when the vector is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use smart pointers then the first solution is correct

Answer (score 1):

First of all, calling `clear()` in the destructor is redundant.

Other than that, it depends.

Roughly, your `vector<Composant*> Composants;` can mean two different things:

1. `Composants` **observes** `Composant` objects which are allocated and deallocated elsewhere. In this case, your second version is correct, because if you only observe a thing which belongs to someone else, then you don't want to destroy it. In modern C++, this is often the only good use case for raw pointers.
2. `Composants` **allocates** the `Composant` objects by itself (using `new`). In this case, `Componsants` is also responsible for deallocation and your second version is *basically* correct. However, in modern C++, you typically do not use `new` and `delete` directly. You instead use `std::unique_ptr` so that deallocation is handled automatically. For certain use cases, `std::shared_ptr` can be used as well.

There is also a third possibility. Perhaps dynamic allocation of the `Componsant` objects is not needed at all. Perhaps `vector<Componsant>` is sufficient, much like `vector<int>` or `<vector<string>>` is typically sufficient. C++ beginners have the tendency to **overuse dynamic allocation** (which is perhaps due to the influence of languages like Java where instances of custom types always have to be created with the `new` keyword).